# Thymeleaf как установить значение переменной?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

```html
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Id day:</label>
          <input  th:value="${ID}" class="form-control" />
          <a th:href="@{${train.id}+'/days/'+${ID}}" class="btn btn-default">Add</a>
        </div>
```

Пытаюсь ввести в поле значение id , и сгенерировать новый url с этим id , вроде days/id

Как это сделать ? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы хотите, чтобы пользователь ввёл в input знаечение 42, например, и после этого ссылка `Add` приняла вид `/13/days/42`?

Comment: Да, именно так .

Comment: Вам надо разобраться в понятиях фронтенд и бэкенд. То, что вам нужно делается на фронте с помощью javascript.

Comment: а без javascript можно как-то ?

Comment: и можно с кодом как это сделать  ? Просто с фронтом не особо дружу

Comment: Шаблонизатор Thymeleaf работает на стороне сервера, задолго до того, как пользователь увидит форму. Это как если бы я сейчас решил уравнение, нарисовал его график на листе бумаги, а потом запаковал в конверт и отправил вам. Если вы на полученном листе напишите x = 42, нарисованный мной график не изменится.

Comment: Понятно, а можно тогда этот пример с использованием js , был бы очень признателен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('day');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var href = button.getAttribute('href');
  button.setAttribute('href', href + input.value);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Id day:</label>
  <input id="day" name="day" class="form-control" />
  <a id="button" href="/13/days/" class="btn btn-default">Add</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !